# How do I get pictures of other Villagers?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I was reading on the Wiki, and it says you can get a picture of a friend. How do I get a friend to give me a picture so I collect as many I can encase any of them decide to move away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be as friendly as you can be to these neighbors, meaning running errands for them, sending them gifts and letters (can't be too short), etc. Basically, building up your relationship with them.

And only then, they may send you a picture of themselves as a keepsake.

Comment: Will they send it after they move away or when ever.

Comment: In my experience, villagers send a letter with their picture when they move out. You can also look into http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Picture#In_New_Leaf

Comment: Yeah, but only if they are on very good terms with you. Not every villager that leaves will send you their picture.